# gphotofs protocol error mounting Android device in PTP mode

Tags: linux, mount, android

I have connected an Android 5.1 device to a Linux machine and I would like to mount it with PTP, as it seem to be easer to copy/remove files than using MTP connection.

In this case, I have loaded the **fuse** module and I mount the device into the system as root. However, I get a protocol error when doing any operation with the file system, such as ls or df:

(launching **gphotofs** in debug mode: gphotofs -o allow_root -d /folder

```
statfs /
   unique: 3, error: -71 (Protocol error), outsize: 16
```

In an Ubuntu 10.04 machine I have mounted it without problems using the same binary and library...so it seems in the other machine a component is missing.

What could I do? Is it better MTP than PTP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lsof` I discovered that two libraries were not installed on the machine, so I copied them:

```
/usr/lib/libgphoto2/2.4.8/ptp2.so
/usr/lib/libgphoto2_port/0.8.0/usb.so
```

Then, `gphotofs` started to work correctly.

Regards.